# How to get resultant row count when reading data from any BigQuery table and write to destination BQ table (Using bigquery.QueryJobConfig())?

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dml

I am doing some read write operations on BigQuery using python client libraries, I would like to know how many rows the "bigquery.QueryJobConfig()" API is reading from source BQ table.

I already tried "query_job._query_results.total_rows" which is a protected member, but its giving me count of total number of rows available in destination BQ table. I also tried "results.total_rows" but it always gives me None as output even though the records are there in source BQ table. I have also tried "result = job.result(), page = result.pages" but as such no expected output.

```
def main(request):

    query = "select * from `myproject.mydataset.mytable`"
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    dest_dataset = client.dataset(destination_dataset, destination_project)
    dest_table = dest_dataset.table(destination_table)
    job_config.destination = dest_table
    job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED'
    job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'
    job = client.query(query, location='US', job_config=job_config)
    job.result()
    results = query_job.result()
    print("Got {} rows.".format(results.total_rows))
    print("Got {} rows.".format(query_job._query_results.total_rows))
```

I want count of total number of rows my query is reading from source table(`myproject.mydataset.mytable`)

Based on my knowledge I am preparing one workaround is that to get the resultant row count first I will count rows in exists in destination table before I perform write to BQ operation and again will count rows from destination table after write to BQ operation. The subtraction of both will give me resultant row count (newly_added_rows = (row_count_after.num_rows - row_count_before.num_rows)
        print("{} rows are found as query result".format(newly_added_rows))) and (if row_count_before.num_rows == row_count_after.num_rows) then query executed with empty result set.
Just Wanted to know whether I am following right approach ?

Answer (score 0):

When BigQuery executes a job, the job is broken into a series of query stages, on each stage you can get the number of input and output rows for each stage, query Plan Explanation gives you the possibility to get this metric [1]

By calling jobs.get [2] you can retrieve job details and you will get the query plan and timeline information.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation#api_sample_representation